# Como Configurar uma connection string

Tags: c#, dapper

Estou querendo conectar com o banco de dados mas a minha minha connection string não está iniciando.

Erro: https://prnt.sc/ngeqde

Classe **`Startup`**:

```
var connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PokemonBD");

services.AddTransient<IDataBaseContext>(contex => 
    new DatabaseContext(new SqlConnection()));

services.AddTransient<IpokemonRepository, PokemonRepository>();
```

**AppSetting.Development.json**

```
 "ConnectionString": {
    "PokemonBD": "Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DbPokemon;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}
```

Comment: Permissão não aceita, parece usuario e senha errado

Comment: Não é, usando os mesmo ID e Pass, para me conectar no Azure Data Studio

Comment: `services.AddTransient< IDataBaseContext >(contex => new DatabaseContext(new SqlConnection(connectionString )));` tente assim

Comment: Já fiz isso, não funcionou

Comment: coloque a classe: `DatabaseContext`

Comment: Resolveu, mas apareceu outro problema, mas mesmo obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou passar a string de conexão pro `SqlConnection`.

```
var connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PokemonBD");

services.AddTransient<IDataBaseContext>(contex => 
     new DatabaseContext(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));

services.AddTransient<IpokemonRepository, PokemonRepository>();
```

Comment: Acabei de passar, mas o problema ainda continua

Comment: @B.Martins O problema continua ou é outro erro?

Comment: Resolvi esse problema, mudei de IDataBaseContext  para DataBaseContext, mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: @B.Martins Entendi foi nada, mas enfim. Se a resposta te ajudou vc pode marcá-la como correta usando o **V** do lado esquerdo